# How to compare bcrypt password to check if a password is correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I'm new to RoR and I'm trying to create a simple board like reddit but without user account.

I want the author of a post can update his post with a password.

Actually I have simply followed the code on bcrypt gems's github

Article model

```
require 'bcrypt'

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  # users.password_hash in the database is a :string
  include BCrypt

  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end
end
```

Article controller

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  @article.password = params[:password]
  @article.save!
end
```

and now I'm trying to do the edit part same as their login which is like this

```
def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  if @article.password == params[:password]
    render 'edit'
  else
    redirect_to @article
  end
end
```

But its comparing my hash in database with the string entered by the user but I read somewhere when you use `==` in rails it's changing the hash by the string or something like that.

I found other solution with the method `authenticate` but it's too much for my use, I simply want to check if the password match.

Sorry if my question sounds stupid.

I'm using Rails 5

Comment: You need a constant time, character-by-character, compare function. Do you know if Ruby provides one? (Probably not since Ruby security is not too impressive).

Answer (score 0):

in your edit action you should use this

```
BCrypt::Password.new(@article.password) == params[:password]
```

Comment: It keeps comparing my hash password with a string, when I try to puts `BCrypt::Password.new(@article.password)` it return me the hash of my password